# making a link "noAJAX"

Tags: javascript

I have this script which is deprecated:

```
   $(function(){ 
  // Link handling.
  $('a[rel != "noAJAX"]').live('click', function(event){    
    if ($(this).attr('name') != ""){        
        var currentDiv = $(this).attr('name');      
    }else{      
        var currentDiv = divID;         
    }   
    $(currentDiv).html(loadingHTML);        
    $(currentDiv).load($(this).attr('href'));   
    event.preventDefault();     
  });
```

I'm trying to apply the `noAJAX` to this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('.no li a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-10)){
            var toLoad = hash+' #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

        $('.no li a').click(function(){

            var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
            $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
            $('#load').remove();
            $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
            $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
            function loadContent() {
                $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
            }
            function showNewContent() {
                $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
            }
            function hideLoader() {
                $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
            }
            return false;

        });

    });
```

so that when I have href links on my page, I can apply the "noAJAX" to the script so it doesn't do anything to certain links. Is this possible? or is there anyone who can guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector.

You could do something like:

```
$('.no li a').not('[rel == "noAJAX"]').click(function(){
    // ...
});
```

Or continue to do it how you were in the previous script:

```
$('.no li a[rel != "noAJAX"]').click(function(){
    // ...
});
```

Or if you do not want to use the rel attribute, add `noAJAX` as a class selector:

```
$('.no li a').not('.noAJAX').click(function(){
    // ...
});
```